# OnClick button set animation on another button

Tags: java, android

This is my code for animate my button:

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,view.getHeight());
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and I want than when I click on this button animation start on another button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
final Button anotherButton = (Button) findViewById(/*your_another_button_id*/);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener
({
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,anotherButton.getHeight());
        animate.setDuration(500);
        animate.setFillAfter(true);
        anotherButton.startAnimation(animate);
        anotherButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post more code pertaining to the other button it might help but I would suggest animating it using the animate in the View:

`view.animate().yby(view.getHeight). setDuration(500).start();`